# Invoke constructor inside a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to invoke a constructor inside of a linq query.

I am getting this error:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Here's my linq query:

```
IQueryable<Object> list = (from u in db.Object select new Object(u));
```

Here is my constructor:

```
public Object(Object presentation){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a contructor without parameters.

```
public Object()
{
    public Object Presentation { get; set; }
}

IQueryable list= (from u in db.Object select new Object { Presentation = u });
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer
public Object()
{
    public Object Presentation { get; set; }
}

Answer (score 6):

```
IQueryable list = db.Object.Select(o => new Object(o))
```