# C# linq changed constructor can't add new value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to LinQ and started working with it a couple weeks ago. So maybe i have the wrong understanding how LinQ works. i also tried to use an empty constructor as stated here: [Invoke constructor inside a linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144884/invoke-constructor-inside-a-linq-query)

I changed the constructor of a class. I added the entity `energyType`

```
public CSVMeter(int meterID, DateTime datum, int numberOfValues, double total, double total2, double qualityScore, int energyType)
    {
        this.MeterID = meterID;
        this.Datum = datum;
        this.NumberOfValues = numberOfValues;
        this.total = total;
        this.total2 = total2;
        this.qualityScore = qualityScore;
        this.energyType = energyType;
    }
```

I have the following LinQ query.

```
 public List<CSVMeter> getDisctinctMeters(List<CSVMeter> meterList)
    {
                    newMeterList = newMeterList.GroupBy(x => new { x.MeterID, x.Datum })
            .Select(x => new CSVMeter(
                x.Key.MeterID, 
                x.Key.Datum, 
                x.Sum(s => s.NumberOfValues), 
                x.Sum(s => s.total), 
                x.Sum(s => s.total2), 
                0, 
                x.energyType))
                .ToList();

        return meterList;

    }
```

but i get the following error at `x.energyType`

> Error 2   'System.Linq.IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'energyType' and no extension method 'energyType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\users\rudi\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\plooscassandra\plooscassandra\handlers\meterbuilder.cs  108 136 PloosCassandra

Why can't i find `x.energyType` ?

Comment: Because that last `x` is not a single `CsvMeter` but an `IGrouping<CsvMeter>` with  your anonymous type (`{MeterID, Datum}`) as `Key` and representing a sequence of `CsvMeter`. The `energyType` would be a property of the `s` you use in the `Sum` calls.

Comment: what is the definition for this object `newMeterList`

Comment: You are grouping your data so energyType doesn't exists as a scalar field but as a list (like NumberOfValues and totals).

Comment: @RenéVogt @ema But `energyType` is not something i want to add up. Its a fixed value i get. I can't use `x.Avarage` because that returns a double value and it is an int.

Comment: @Proliges see my answer. And how "fixed" is this value? If it's the same for all, you can use my `First()` approach. If it's totally constant, maybe an instance property in `CsvMeter` is a wrong place to store it at all.

Comment: @RenéVogt did that, worked. Marked as correct. Btw its not totally constant. But the value is fixed once i retrieve it from a database. Its based on the `meterID`. But it can fluctuate when i use an other `meterID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do a grouping, the `x` in the `Select`'s lambda is an `IGrouping<CsvMeter>` - not a *single* `CsvMeter`.

This `IGrouping<CsvMeter>` has a `Key` property of the anonymous type you created above and further represents a sequence of `CsvMeter` instances.

Since you already did sum `Sum` operations on that sequence, you actually should have known that. The question is, how you want to *aggregate* the `energyType` of all `CsvMeter` instances in the sequence to evaluate the `energyType` for your resulting new `CsvMeter`. Here is how to simply use the `energyType` of the first element in the group:

```
newMeterList.GroupBy(x => new { x.MeterID, x.Datum })
            .Select(x => new CSVMeter(
                x.Key.MeterID, 
                x.Key.Datum, 
                x.Sum(s => s.NumberOfValues), 
                x.Sum(s => s.total), 
                x.Sum(s => s.total2), 
                0, 
                x.First().energyType))
            .ToList();
```

`First()` returns the first `CsvMeter` instace in the group.

---

But maybe you actually wanted to group the `CsvMeter` instances by that energy type, too. So you could change the grouping to

```
newMeterList.GroupBy(x => new { x.MeterID, x.Datum, x.energyType })
      //...
```

and use that value in the `Select`:

```
.Select(x => new CSVMeter(
     x.Key.MeterID, 
     x.Key.Datum, 
     x.Sum(s => s.NumberOfValues), 
     x.Sum(s => s.total), 
     x.Sum(s => s.total2), 
     0, 
     x.Key.energyType))
```

---

BTW your code look a little weird: your `getDisctinctMeters` takes a parameter called `meterList` and that is returned without any change. Instead you use some `newMeterList` and did not show its declaration. For my answer I assumed your intention was this:

```
public List<CSVMeter> getDisctinctMeters(List<CSVMeter> meterList)
{
    var newMeterList = meterList.GroupBy // shortened for clarity
    return newMeterList;
}
```

Comment: but it is also possible that the class used to create `newMeterList` instance  does not have the property `energyType` since he is not using the `meterList` passed value

Comment: @Sherlock Updated the answer to address this

Comment: @RenéVogt  Okay i tried the `x.first()` option and it looks like this is the correct answer. Since the `energyType` is always the same. returning the first one is always correct. 
Also: about the code looking weird. Thats correct, i did not post the entire class since it would just be filling the page with useless information. I just used the pieces i had issues with.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `GroupBy` is `IGouping`, representing the groups themselves, not `IEnumerable<CSVMeter>`, so `x` has no property `energyType`. That being said, you would have to clarify for which member of the group the `energyType` would have to be selected; `energyType` is not used in the grouping expression.

Comment: but it is also possible that the class used to create `newMeterList` instance  does not have the property `energyType` since he is not using the `meterList` passed value